# Where is system update option located in Alldaymall A88S tablet?

Tags: updates

I recently brought my sister a Alldaymall A88S tablet. Anyway, I cannot find the system update function (or at least, I didn't see it). Where is it?

And no root methods  please.

Comment: To update apps or Android OS?

Comment: @FiN Android OS

Comment: I am at the screen where it says use adb sideload <filename> and need to load it up to be normal, without all the pornclub crapola that persists between factory resets.  Installing Android SDK right now.  So I need the image to download.  I might be able to get shell access and will mark everything 777 so maybe can clean it out.

Comment: @SDsolar the device has long since stopped working (charger port quite literally fell out) but thanks for your interest nonetheless

Comment: Understood.  I lost the original charger but it will charge from the micro USB port.  I posted a question on this.  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181337/alldaymall-a88s-popping-up-a-bunch-of-junk-from-pornclub-i-have-it-rooted-now and am getting some tips.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Settings **>** About tablet **>** System Updates/Update Center

Comment: Alirght. I'll check once it is charged (they charge quickly,so....)

Comment: it is not there.

Comment: @DanB The option would be there if the OEM decided to support the device for  updates. For e.g. My JB device by an OEM doesn't have any OTA functionality but my KK device by same OEM is OTA supported.

Comment: @Firelord Well, by that logic.... Fair enough. I do have devices ensured to be at their final, but still have an update functionality/client.