# Can/How to Update Alldaymall a88s Android 4.4 to 5.0?

Tags: updates

Recently received donated tablets for our school. I need to update the Android software in order to use them. I have looked under settings, also in the Google Playstore & did a factory update. I need Android 5.0 to run the PaySimple app we use for our card reader. I have looked for manufacturer information but cannot find anything on them (manual, website, support). They are Alldaymall a88s tablets.

Comment: it is not possible because there is no official update available https://android.stackexchange.com/q/120553 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/181337 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224047

Comment: @alecxs Thank you! I am new to Android & tablets. So I cannot upgrade the Android software like you can with Windows (uninstall windows & install the new version)? There were about 50 of these donated to our school & we won't be able to use them if we cannot update them.

Comment: no, android must compiled from source code device specific. request the source code from manufacturer and find a developer who can do it. another solution maybe ROM can ported from other device with Allwinner A33 chipset